# Coldfusion 9 Inter portlet communication?

Tags: coldfusion, jboss, ipc, portlet, liferay

I am having a hard time trying to find documentation at achieving IPC using Coldfusion 9 portlets under JBOSS.  Does anyone have any good references I can take a look at? Or maybe some example code that I can go off of?

So far I've been successful in getting my portlets working under Liferay (JBOSS), form submission, different views (edit/help) all work fine.

Just need to know how to have one portlet on the page talk with another portlet.  So far have been unsuccessful :(

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, my recommendation is to avoid Inter-Portlet Communication. Currently it's outside the spec (for JSR-168, though 286 introduces some concepts like shared-render params) If you're using Liferay or JBOSS portal (regardless of container) you should be able to do:

- shared render params
- events

I'm not sure if you'd have any special work to get these going with whatever bridge you/Coldfusion uses to integrate with portlets.

See: http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr286/index.html, though different containers currently have different levels of compliance - hard to provide more details w/o version numbers, etc.